# jQuery 1.11.3: Insert a div of "Tasks" based on the order of their categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

In my own "ToDoList" where you can add tasks, delete them, and check/uncheck them with their corresponding checkboxes, and all the tasks are displayed in order by their corresponding categories, which in Django, is stored as a CharField.

However, there's a problem I'm noticing. When I am adding a new task that its category is new, the div that holds the category name is added at the bottom of my list instead of added in the place where it should go to make my categories in the list in Unicode order. And so, I'm wondering what I need to do to make my list in order when I add tasks at runtime instead of having to let Django render an ordered task list by clicking on the Refresh button.

Here's my JavaScript code; it uses jQuery (for simplicity, I'm only showing the function that's called after the POST request has been made when the user clicks on the "Add Task" button and there is a character in the "Task" input field):

```
$.post("process-request", {new_task: taskInput, category_of_task: categoryOfTask}, function () {
            $.get("retrieve-actual-id-of-model-after-adding-task", {category_of_task: categoryOfTask}, function(data) {
                newTask.attr("task_id", data.id_of_last_task_added);

                if ($("#category__" + categoryOfTask).length == 0)
                {
                    if ($("#category__").length == 0)
                        var newDiv = $("<div id=\"category__" + categoryOfTask + "\"><span>" + categoryOfTask + "</span>");
                    else
                        var newDiv = $("<br/><div id=\"category__" + categoryOfTask + "\"><span>" + categoryOfTask + "</span>");
                    $("#listOfThingsToDo").append(newDiv);
                    $("#listOFThingsToDO").append("</div>");
                    newDiv.show();
                }

                $("#category__" + categoryOfTask).append(newTask);
            });
        });
```

Here are a couple of images to show a better picture:

[image: List rendered by the Django template with tasks already existing]

A category-based sorted list, as it is rendered by the Django template when the Refresh button is clicked and tasks do exist for the logged in user.

[image: Unsorted List at runtime after I add a new task with a new category]
Unsorted List at runtime after I add a new task with a new category

Please let me know if you need to see additional code; just let me know what kind of code you need to see based on the jQuery code I got here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the categories you already have and then use a $insertAfter or $prepend in case of the first sorted category. 
Take a look on this working example based on the code you gave:
https://jsfiddle.net/e6g4fu84/

```
// ADDING A NEW TASK IN A NEW CATEGORY

    categoryOfTask = "baa";

    newtask = document.createElement("task");
    $(newtask).html('<div><input type="checkbox"/><label>task foo inserted</label></div>');


// When you gonna add your new category holder add it like this:
    if ($("#category__" + categoryOfTask).length == 0){


  //Create your new Div just like you have done  
      if ($("#category__").length == 0)
         var newDiv = $("<div id=\"category__" + categoryOfTask + "\"><span>" + categoryOfTask + "</span></div>");
      else
         var newDiv = $("<br/><div id=\"category__" + categoryOfTask + "\"><span>" + categoryOfTask + "</span></div>");


   //But the trick happens when you will add your new category holder
   //----------------------------------------------------------


   //find all elements that have #category__X as id
        categoriesElements = $("#listOfThingsToDo div[id*=category__]");


   //And then add them on an array
        categoriesNames = [];
        $.each(categoriesElements, function(i, category){
            categoriesNames.push($(category).attr("id").split("__")[1]);
        });


    //Add your new category to the group and sort

        categoriesNames.push(categoryOfTask);
        categoriesNames.sort();


    //find where you should fit
        putCategoryAfter = categoriesNames.indexOf(categoryOfTask) - 1;


    //Then add it where it should be
        if(putCategoryAfter == -1) //If it's the first of the list
            $("#listOfThingsToDo").prepend(newDiv);    
        else{ //If it isn't the first find where it should be and insert it there
           $(newDiv).insertAfter("#category__"+categoriesNames[putCategoryAfter]);
        }

       newDiv.show();
}


// And after all add your task to it
    $("#category__" + categoryOfTask).append(newtask);
```

I comment the steps to clarify, hope i could help. 
If this is what you are expecting just let me know. Best regards! :-)

Comment: This works, but now I encountered a very different problem. It's when I put in special characters in my category because I'm getting "Syntax error: unrecognized expression".

Comment: I know I'm supposed to use backslashes in front of these special characters and have tried both using encodeURI and encodeURIComponent to do so, but it seems that I'm still getting these errors in the Google Chrome console. I'm wondering what's a better way to represent the ids of the category divs; numbers are problematic for your answer.